# Can't find the element ANYHOW

Tags: python, selenium, find, webdriver, element

```
<iframe id="iframe10737" _color="main_gray" src="cn.edu.sufe.ext.stuAct.protal.queryActByType.flow?dlid=10737&amp;color=main_gray" width="100%" height="450px" frameborder="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="yes">
  #document
    <html class="js cssanimations">
        <head>...</head>
        <body style="background-color:#fff;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
            <ul data-am-widget="gallery" class="am-gallery am-avg-sm-2   am-avg-md-5 am-avg-lg-4 am-gallery-bordered am-no-layout" data-am-gallery="{  }">
                  ::before
                <li>
                    <a href="/ext/cn.edu.sufe.ext.stuAct.actDetail.flow?id=28da6cbbe5d44b7a9074c26a0d1f22a0" target="_blank">
                        <div style="padding:10px 0px;">
                            <img src="cn.edu.sufe.common.util.FileDownload.flow?fileid=af55af7c42cd498c904d7a092945382b" style="width:170px;height:127px;" width="170px" height="127px">
                            <h3 class="am-gallery-title">Outdoor Sport Association</h3>
                            <div class="am-gallery-desc">start time：</div>
                            <div class="am-gallery-desc">end time：2018-01-17</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                  ::after
            </ul>
        </body>
</iframe>
```

I need to find the element and click it:

```
<h3 class="am-gallery-title">Outdoor Sport Association</h3>
```

I have try a lot, but it still unsolved.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h3[class="am-gallery-title"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("am-gallery-title").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Outdoor Sport Association")]').click()

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Outdoor Sport Association').click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h3.Outdoor Sport Association').click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('/body/ul/li/a/div/h3').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="js cssanimations"]/body/div[2]/div/h1/a').click()
```

Those methods don't work at all.Its all say:

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element:{...}

.
Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h3` element is located inside an `iframe`. To be able to handle it, you need to switch to that `iframe` first:

```
driver.switch_to_frame('iframe10737')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[text()="Outdoor Sport Association"]')
```

Comment: It's the 'iframe'! It works! Thank you very much! So excited about learning this!